# How do you reference a certificate stored in a keyvault from an application gateway ARM Template?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template, azure-application-gateway, azure-managed-identity

This may be relatively new stuff, but I am looking for a way to reference a certificate already stored in the keyvault certificates. The application gateway needs a managed identity to do so. At the interface level in the portal, I have no issues, but how is this done in an Application Gateway ARM Template?

- the keyvault exists with the certificates
- using an [Application Gateway ARM Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/applicationgateways?tabs=json)
- with a [User Assigned Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/applicationgateways?tabs=json#managedserviceidentity-object) resource ID to access the certificates in the keyvault
- but, when we get to the [Application Gateway Certificates Property Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/applicationgateways?tabs=json#applicationgatewaysslcertificatepropertiesformat-object) A, I am afraid I don't know how to reference the certificate object properly, specifically the **keyVaultSecretId**

Even though this is referenced as such: "keyVaultSecretId": "string"
AND it asks for "Secret Id of (base-64 encoded unencrypted pfx) 'Secret' or 'Certificate' object stored in KeyVault", placing in the secret Id does not work. My question to you is, what am I doing wrong? How do I reference a certificate stored in a keyvault here for the ssl certificate?

By placing secretId String of the certificate, I get an internal service error. Is this correct in what I am doing, or do I need a different Id? does the bracket need to specify only the name of the certificate with the id of the keyvault?

*breakdown of simple code*

```
"type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways",    
"properties": {    
       "sslCertificates": [
                        {
                            "name": "[parameters('sslCert').name]",
                            "properties": {
                                "keyVaultSecretId": "[parameters('sslCert').secretId]"
                                }
                            }
                        }]
    },
    "identity": {
                    "type": "UserAssigned",
                    "userAssignedIdentities": {
                        "[concat('/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/',parameters('appGateway').userAssignedResourceId)]": {}
                    }
    },
```

Comment: Your secretId is in the format `https://vaultname.vault.azure.net/secrets/certificatename` ? Note `/secrets/` in the path even though this is a certificate.

Comment: yes, that format + a trailing forward slash and few numbers '/######################'. This information is labelled as the secret Id in the stored keyvault certficate.

Comment: You might try removing the secret version (the "/######" part). I don't have that in my working template. Also, are you sure your application gateway has network access to the key vault?

Comment: Thank you, in the process of deploying without that. The gateway does have network access.

Comment: I get a status that says "Conflict", and an internal service type error. Also, when you say network access to the keyvault, it is being routed through the firewall.

Comment: Where do I check if my application gateway has access to my keyvault?

Comment: That's in the firewall or network settings for your key vault. See step 2 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/key-vault-certs#how-integration-works